# Inconsistent Flask request behavior

Tags: python, flask, aws-lambda

I have a simple flask app that receives an encoded json file in a url, prints it out and imports it in to a dictionary object my_dict:

```
from flask import request
import json

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def test:
  rqa = request.args.get('data', '')
  print(rqa)
  my_dict = json.loads(rqa)
```

I need to pass input from a form field that may contain quotes, etc., which I first encode using `encodeURIComponent()`

```
var dict = {
    'key': encodeURIComponent('red ("old") fox')
    };

var dict_en = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(dict));
```

Using dict_en, I create a url for the flask app:

```
http://localhost:5000/test?data=%7B%22key%22%3A%22red%2520(%2522old%2522)%2520fox%22%7D
```

When I run this locally using flask, it works fine and the result from request.args can be turned in to a dictionary object using json.loads()

```
{"key":"red%20(%22old%22)%20fox"}
```

The problem is when I run this same code on AWS Lambda, request.args decodes my string twice, which then cannot be converted to a dictionary object due to the unescaped double quotes:

```
{"key":"red ("old") fox"}
```

How do I ensure flask.request works consistently in the two environments?

Both environments use Python 3.8.3, Flask 1.1.2, Werkzeug 0.16.1

Comment: your issue is most likely with (your setup and/or) AWS. how is do you deploy your flask in lambda? lambda receives a json event, so when you run an entire flask app in lambda there surely must be some kind of magic that transforms your event into a flask request and call flask to handle it somehow?

Comment: ...also e.g. the ALB, GW (or whatever is calling your lambda) usually does some url decoding already. might be that your ALB url decodes the data param and then flask does it again, hence %2522 --(alb)--> %22 --(flask)--> "

Comment: I'm using Zappa to upload my Flask app to AWS.   Older versions of my code are working fine and I haven't knowingly updated any of the libraries.    in this version.

Comment: My understanding is that flask.request tries to 'guess' what the appropriate decoding is.  By default it decodes the string once, which is fine, but now appears to do it a second time likely because it detects escaped characters after decoding once.  Can you change its default behavior.

Comment: ...as I said. from my experience with AWS i know for sure AWS _does_ some (sometimes annoying) conversion of requests. if you say "I'm using Zappa..." it means you have an unknown number of "magic" intermediary layers of (deployment) logic to your app when you deploy to AWS - that's imho the most like source of the issue. raw flask is deterministic, so there's no reason it would behave differently on AWS (unless maybe you'd use some vastly different versions locally). I'd still bet on AWS ;-)
I'd check aws logs to see _exactly_ what the request looks like that flask receives...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are right about Zappa and the 'magic' layers.  I checked the logs and that is how I discovered request was decoding it twice.  Was hoping to avoid updating Python/Flask/Zappa to newer versions as that caused a whole set of other problems the last time I did it.  Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: what logs did you check? your application logs inside your flask code (that already receives the twice decoded params) or the actual AWS infrastructure logs that tell you what happens _before_ flask receives the request?

Comment: I use   zappa tail dev  to view the logs.  That is where I can see the URL string is properly being received - meaning it is the same as when I run it locally.

Comment: what _exactly_ do you deploy? lambda can't be called via http by itself, it's either configured as a handler behind an AWS load balancer or an api gateway....plus zappa as an integration layer to convert incoming AWS json events into a flask request as expected by your code....so you have

%2522 --(http)--> alb/api gw --(json event)--> aws lambda --> zappa integration magic --(flask request object)--> %22 --> flask --> " (your code)

Comment: the only thing you run locally is flask, so your issue can be either in the aws alb/api gw OR the zappa integration magic. zappa apparently is a black box, so you don't know what it actually logs (raw incoming requests vs processed requests). what i would do is check the aws cloudwatch logs directly in the aws console. you can also trigger a lambda manually in the aws console by feeding it an aws event (structure see aws docs) - if you compare your input with what flask receives you'll see what zappa does with it. that way you might be able to track the issue down...

Answer (score 1):

...in addition to our conversation in the comments section...

...I found the concept of doubly urlencoding json highly unusual...quotes are valid chars actually. so before you launch yourself into some overly time consuming debugging of your aws tech stack (welcome to the public cloud by the way), have you tried the following?

...remove the encodeURIComponent inside of the dict...which should produce some nice, standard, urlencoded string...

```js
// feed this test-string: !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABC[\]^_`abc{|}滑串ごさ~ڔ ڕ ږ
// into your system (here by simple user promt):
let userinput = prompt("Enter any string: ", "");
var dict = {
    'key': userinput
};
var s = JSON.stringify(dict)
// {"key":"!\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABC[\\]^_`abc{|}滑串ごさ~ڔ ڕ ږ"}
var dict_en = encodeURIComponent(s);
console.log(dict_en);
//%7B%22key%22%3A%22!%5C%22%23%24%25%26'()*%2B%2C-.%2F0123456789%3A%3B%3C%3D%3E%3F%40ABC%5B%5C%5C%5D%5E_%60abc%7B%7C%7D%EF%A4%84%EF%A4%85%E3%81%94%E3%81%95~%DA%94%20%DA%95%20%DA%96%22%7D
```

...that you then send to your AWS/Zappa deployed flask backend...which will basically do the following magic to decode your urlencoded data parameter

```py
import json
import urllib.parse

data = """%7B%22key%22%3A%22!%5C%22%23%24%25%26'()*%2B%2C-.%2F0123456789%3A%3B%3C%3D%3E%3F%40ABC%5B%5C%5C%5D%5E_%60abc%7B%7C%7D%EF%A4%84%EF%A4%85%E3%81%94%E3%81%95~%DA%94%20%DA%95%20%DA%96%22%7D""" 
# received by HTTP
for i in range(100):
    data = urllib.parse.unquote(received)
# {"key":"!\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABC[\\]^_`abc{|}滑串ごさ~ڔ ڕ ږ"}
```

...which is then available inside of your flask route and can be parsed as json just like so

```py
import json
// data = request.args.get('data', '')
p = json.loads(data)
print(p)
```

...producing a perfectly fine python dict:

```
{'key': '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABC[\\]^_`abc{|}滑串ごさ~ڔ ڕ ږ'}
```

=> the point being: I wouldn't trust your AWS/Zappa/Flask blackbox to urldecode your parameters *exactly* once, twice or three times...that's very brittle...and breaks easily as you noticed. as a matter of fact url decoding should actually be idempotent, that is, decoding an already decoded string 100 times should not change the result as long as there are no url encoded chars in the string...so you just encode it *ONCE* on the javascript side and in flask expect it to be already fully decoded when you access it in flask's request context...that way it should work locally and also on AWS...you just have to be sure it is urldecode n > 1 times (which is already ensured by flask itself)

**UPDATE 11/05/2023**: updated sample string to include some special chars and also some chinese, japanese and arabic characters to cover input an international user base might possibly feed into your system
**UPDATE 13/05/2023**: fixed copy/paste bug in the javascript sample

Comment: I really appreciate the help and agree with your thoughts.  My problem is a bit more general, meaning I'm passing the contents from an input search field where any characters can be included such as single & double quotes, back & forward slashes, commas, question mark, etc.  Not uncommon to have single and double quotes in the same string.  I could escape all characters that could cause problems but was hoping for a more robust solution like encodeURIcomponent.

Comment: that's the point, man...your solution *depends* on the fact that your string is decoded **exactly** once and only once (by flask)...which isn't the case when deployed to aws...counting on your aws/zappa blackbox combo to behave in that subtle way (not to decode at all) is...let's say, very optimistic...the simple fact you have this bug now proves your solution is **not** robust. have you actually tested my proposed solution with special characters?...because i did and it should work just fine (although I cannot test your deployed app)...

Comment: ...i've updated the code snippet above. in the javascript part you'll find a sample string with special characters. make the change i proposed, feed the string into your deployed system and see what happens

Comment: ...it seems your confusion stems from the fact that you enter a string like _aa"bb"cc'd'e_ in your form and when you _display/print_ it, it shows _"aa"bb"cc'd'e"_ giving you the impression javascript/python turns it into sth invalid. this is not the case: your programming language does **not** add anything to your string, it just uses quotes to tell you: this is a string and/or to allow *you* to tell it: this is a string. otherwise, how could you tell it you want x = "343" to be a string instead of an int?

Comment: I tried your solution just to confirm why I did what I did in the first place.  I can't rely on jsonify to do the encoding due to the use of backslashes in the input.  The ampersand symbol is used as the boolean connector AND (old & fox) as well as part of a name (fox \& fiddle pub)  where the ampersand is escaped to denote a search that includes that character.  In the approach you suggested, it would unencoded \& to &, which is indistinguishable from the boolean operator &.